# Clojure macro: getting syntax-quoted/namespace-qualified symbol

Tags: clojure, macros

Let’s say that I want to define a macro called `defsomething` such that this:

```
(defspecial a x)
```

…expands into this:

```
(def a (f `a x))
```

That syntax-quotation `` `a `` there is the tricky part. I don’t see how I can attach the current namespace to the symbol properly so that it behaves like the syntax-quote. For instance:

```
(defmacro defspecial [var-symbol expr]
  `(def ~var-symbol (f '~var-symbol ~expr)))

(defspecial a x)
```

…expands into:

```
(def a (f 'a x))
```

…which is close, but that second `a` is not namespace-qualified.

I know I *could* use `*ns*`:

```
(defmacro defspecial [var-symbol expr]
  `(def ~var-symbol (f (symbol (name (ns-name *ns*)) (name '~var-symbol)) ~expr)))
```

…but I don’t like that; not only is it ugly, `*ns*` is rebindable, so this would be possible:

```
(binding [*ns* (the-ns 'clojure.core)]
  (defspecial a 5))
```

Unfortunately, Clojure apparently has no `syntax-quote` form for `` ` `` like it has `quote` for `'`. And so, how should I best implement this macro, then?

Comment: \` doesn't append the current namespace. It's hard to understand what you're trying to achieve without you giving in an example of what you'd like and why it doesn't work (I mean, I get that you want to place a syntax quote somewhere, I'm talking about what your macro is actually supposed to do).

Comment: The background’s that this is for a library that combines functions together to make parsers. One higher-level function (call it `lbl`) takes a function (call it `p`) and wraps it in another function that adds a sort of “label” to whatever `p` returns (for the parse functions’ syntax error handling). I’d like to make a version of `def` for defining parser functions, and I’d like it to automatically call `lbl` on the functions and label them with their vars’ names. Namespace qualification would be nice here, since I anticipate a lot of label collisions otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you actually tried the last example you gave? The compiler's binding of `*ns*` happens at compile-time, as does the macroexpansion, so the run-time binding you do should have no effect on the behavior of `defspecial`.

Comment: Huh! You’re right. I should have tested that beforehand. Looks like this is the answer, though it’s still a little ugly for my tastes, sigh. But thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that works for Clojure and ClojureScript:

```clj
(defn qualify-sym
  [env s]
  (if (:ns env)
    ;; cljs
    (symbol (name (-> env :ns :name)) (name s))

    ;; clj
    (symbol (str *ns*) (str s))))

(defmacro example [name val]
  `(def ~name {:id '~(qualify-sym &env name) :value ~val}))

(example xxx 123)

xxx
;;=>
{:value 123, :id my-ns/xxx}
```

If you need to also take into consideration aliases and refered vars then this a more complete version:

```clj
(defn qualify-sym [env s]
  (if (:ns env)
    ;; cljs
    (if (simple-symbol? s)
      (or (some-> env :ns :uses s name (symbol (name s)))
          (symbol (name (-> env :ns :name)) (name s)))
      (symbol (or (some-> env :ns :requires (get (symbol (namespace s))) name)
                  (namespace s))
              (name s)))

    ;; clj
    (if (simple-symbol? s)
      (or (some-> (ns-refers *ns*) (get s) symbol)
          (symbol (str *ns*) (str s)))
      (let [ns (namespace s)
            n (name s)
            aliases (ns-aliases *ns*)]
        (symbol (or (some-> aliases (get (symbol ns)) ns-name str) ns) n)))))
```

E.g. if you have `(:require [clojure.string :as str])`, then qualifying `str/join` will return `clojure.string/join`